# How to enumerate string from a vector of alphabets

Tags: r, string

I have the following vector of alphabets :

```
my_alphs <- c("X","Y","Z")
```

Given a string with asterisks (*) as a wildcard:

```
my_str <- "LA**"
```

Note that the length of the string can be longer than 4 and 
the position of the asterisk can be anywhere with different lengths.

I would like to enumerate all the asterisk (*) based on the alphabets stored in `my_alphs`, resulting in this ( I do this manually):

```
LAXX
LAXY
LAXZ
LAYX
LAYY
LAYZ
LAZX
LAZY
LAZZ
```

How can I achieve that with R?

Comment: How do you decide which asterisk represents which letter in your `my_alphs`? Or did you just use any possible combinations of your 'my_alphs' vector (depending on the number of asterisks)?

Comment: @Freakazoid all possible combination of `my_alphs` vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `my_str` and `my_alphs` as wanted.

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(stringr)
> library(purrr)
> do.call(expand.grid, list(rep(list(my_alphs), str_count(my_str, "\\*")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) %>%
+   accumulate(function (str, replacement) str_replace(str, "\\*", replacement), .init=my_str) %>%
+   last()
[1] "LAXX" "LAYX" "LAZX" "LAXY" "LAYY" "LAZY" "LAXZ" "LAYZ" "LAZZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base `R` solution that generalises to any number and position of `*`

```
replace_wildcards <- function(str, alphs) {
  strs <- strsplit(str, "")[[1]]
  combs <- do.call(expand.grid, list(alphs)[rep(1, sum(strs == "*"))])
  frame <- do.call(cbind, lapply(strs, rep, NROW(combs)))
  frame[, strs == "*"] <- as.matrix(combs)
  apply(frame, 1, paste, collapse = "")
}
```

Examples:

```
replace_wildcards("LA**", c("X","Y","Z"))
# [1] "LAXX" "LAYX" "LAZX" "LAXY" "LAYY" "LAZY" "LAXZ" "LAYZ" "LAZZ"
replace_wildcards("*N*Y*", c("1", "2"))
# "1N1Y1" "2N1Y1" "1N2Y1" "2N2Y1" "1N1Y2" "2N1Y2" "1N2Y2" "2N2Y2"
replace_wildcards("**_is_here", c("Q", "I", "R"))
# [1] "QQ_is_here" "IQ_is_here" "RQ_is_here" "QI_is_here" "II_is_here" "RI_is_here" "QR_is_here" "IR_is_here" "RR_is_here"
```

Comment: @markus Just do `paste0(., "LA")`? Or i'm missing something?

Comment: That's one option of course but I guess OP looks for a more generic solution. What if the input is `"*L*A*"`.